# How to setup custom breadcrumbs with taxonomy?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have content types that use taxonomy to categorize content. The Pathauto url alias structure is 'content type' / 'taxonomy term' For example:

Food/japanese - where food is the content type and japanese categorizes it.

I am using Custom breadcrumbs with great success except for when viewing a taxonomy page at it's alias. breadcrumbs don't work at all. The term does not show up, the parent does not show up, nothing happens. I have the 'custom breadcrumbs taxonomy' module enabled.

I saw that enabling that sub module created a place where I could create a custom path for each term. Technically I could go through and create a path, but I have 100s, if not over 1000 different terms and more added all the time. It would not be possible to use the term.

This would be very easy if I could just specify 'content type' / 'term' like I do for Path auto. One entry could take care of every situation. Is this possible? anyone know how I can configure this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue in D7 and opted to use Easy Breadcrumb: http://drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb.

Easy Breadcrumb compiles the breadcrumb from the URL, and is simple to set up.  But it seems like it should work in yours.

Here is an example of how it works:

- URL: www.example.com/portfolio/french
- Breadcrumb: Home › Portfolio › French

What is wonderful about Easy Breadcrumb is that it doesn't matter whether you are using content types, taxonomies, views, or whatever, because it only looks at the URL.  *Because* it relies strictly upon the URL, however, it won't be appropriate in many cases.

I wasn't comfortable with how it handled searches (Home › Search › Content › [Search term]) and recently messaged the maintainer about the possibility of being able to list instances in which Easy Breadcrumb would be omitted, and he obliged in the latest release.

Comment: The code in that module inspired a theme function to use the url structure as the taxonomy structure. Because my urls are 'hackable' this works great! Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but you can do that always with [theme_breadcrumb()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7) function in your theme like this:

```
function YOUR_THEME_breadcrumb($vars) {
    $breadcrumb = $vars['breadcrumb'];
    if (count($breadcrumb)) {
        if (arg(0)=='taxonomy' && arg(1)=='term') {
            $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
            if ($term->vid==YOUR_VOCABULARY_VID) {
                $breadcrumb[] = l('Your landing page', 'landing-page-url');
            }
        }
        return '<ul><li>'.implode('<span class="separator">&raquo;</span></li><li>', $breadcrumb).'</li></ul>';
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you're using D7.

Comment: I found that doing this was sufficient for my purposes. I tried Hansel and it was far too convoluted.